# Filtering MySQL COUNT query results

Tags: mysql, sql

I have the following MySQL table called tbl_pet_owners:

```
+----+--------+----------+--------+--------------+
| id | name   | pet      | city   | date_adopted |
+----+--------+----------+--------+--------------+
|  1 | jane   | cat      | Boston | 2017-07-11   |
|  2 | jane   | dog      | Boston | 2017-07-11   |
|  3 | jane   | cat      | Boston | 2017-06-11   |
|  4 | jack   | cat      | Boston | 2016-07-11   |
|  5 | jim    | snake    | Boston | 2017-07-11   |
|  6 | jim    | goldfish | Boston | 2017-07-11   |
|  7 | joseph | cat      | NYC    | 2016-07-11   |
|  8 | sam    | cat      | NYC    | 2017-07-11   |
|  9 | drew   | dog      | NYC    | 2016-07-11   |
+----+--------+----------+--------+--------------+
```

In a previous Stack Overflow post, I asked for help using COUNT to get the number of pets per city, BUT if an individual owns two or more pets of the same type, then those pets are counted as one. The pet types are listed in another MySQL table called tbl_pet_types:

```
+----------+-------------+
| pet      | type        |
+----------+-------------+
| cat      | mammal      |
| dog      | mammal      |
| goldfish | fish        |
| goldfish | seacreature |
| snake    | reptile     |
+----------+-------------+
```

Here is the working code for this:

```
select count(*), result.city from (
    select owners.city, types.type, owners.name
    from tbl_pet_owners owners
    left join tbl_pet_types types on owners.pet = types.pet group by owners.city, owners.name, types.type
) as result
group by result.city;
```

I'm trying to modify the code so that only pets adopted between '2017-01-01' and '2017-08-01' are counted. So in this example, jack's cat, joseph's cat and drew's dog will not be counted.

I've tried adding a where statement to my query, but I'm getting lots of syntax errors:

```
select count(*), result.city from (
    select owners.city, types.type, owners.name
    from tbl_pet_owners owners
    left join tbl_pet_types types on owners.pet = types.pet group by owners.city, owners.name, types.type
) as result where result.date_adopted > '2017-01-01' 
and result.date_adopted < '2017-08-01'
group by result.city;
```

Any tips on how I can achieve this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try something like this:

```
select count(*), result.city from (
    select owners.city, types.type, owners.name
    from tbl_pet_owners owners
    left join tbl_pet_types types on owners.pet = types.pet 
    where owners.date_adopted BETWEEN '2012-12-25 00:00:00' AND '2012-12-25 23:59:59'
    group by owners.city, owners.name, types.type
) as result 
group by result.city;
```

Comment: To improve query performance replace the subselect with a join

Comment: ERROR 1064 (42000): You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version
 for the right syntax to use near 'where owners.date_adopted > '2017-01-01' and owners.date_adopted < '2017-08-01'
' at line 4
mysql>

Comment: Mark as a helpful answer =)